# Rotate an horizontal saved png into vertical [Android]

Tags: java, android, rotation, android-camera

I have an application that clicks images in potrait mode and saves them in SDCARD with exyension png. I am using an additional overlay over the image and then saves it.My images are getting saved in landscape mode.

I tried using matrix but cant get the solution right.

Code: This functions generated the png from an array that contains all images byte data.

```
          public void generatePng(byte[][] global) {


              for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
                 // Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                 // matrix.postRotate();
                  // createa matrix for the manipulation


                  Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(global[i], 0, global[i].length);
                  int wid = cameraBitmap.getWidth();
                  int hgt = cameraBitmap.getHeight();

                  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                  // resize the bit map
                  // matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                  // rotate the Bitmap
                  matrix.postRotate(45);

                  Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap
                          (cameraBitmap,0,0,wid, hgt, matrix,true);

                  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);

                  canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);

                  Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.overlay11);
                 // drawable.
                //  drawable.setBounds(40, 40, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() + 40, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() + 40);
                  drawable.setBounds(0, 0, wid, hgt);

                  drawable.draw(canvas);


                  File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/", "pics");

                  File myImage = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "pic" + glo + ".png");
                  Log.d("naval", "File path :" + myImage);
                  glo++;

                  try {
                      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
                      newImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);


                      out.flush();
                      out.close();
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                      Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");
                  }
              }
              counter =0;
             // camera.startPreview();


          }
```

I think the overlay i use creates problem.
Got 2 questions

1. Can we rotate a saved image rather than at the time of saving. My images are saved perfectly in landscape view.Just wanna rotate them to Potrait.
2. I am trying to create a gif from all these images. Can we rotate a gif?

Comment: `matrix.postRotate(45);` should really be `matrix.postRotate(90);` (or `matrix.postRotate(270);`, to rotate it the other way)!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matrix.postRotate(270);
```

This worked.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest first checking the orientation of the `Bitmap` using `ExifInterface`.

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
```

Then using `Matrix` to rotate the `Bitmap`:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

if (orientation == 6) {
matrix.postRotate(90);
} else if (orientation == 3) {
matrix.postRotate(180);
} else if (orientation == 8) {
matrix.postRotate(270);
}

myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Then you can finally save your rotated `Bitmap` in the sdcard. Make sure to load scaled down Bitmaps into the memory to avoid `java.lang.OutOfMemory` exceptions.